# How to make my imagebuttons bigger in my layout xml file?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

I've arranged my image buttons and textView into a linear layout and I was wondering when I ran the application on the emulator and on my phone the image buttons was equally laid out but the were small and too far apart.

Here is a link of what the picture looks like.
http://i1207.photobucket.com/albums/bb478/Xxsoralover_1001xX/12980419_1141027192594851_48037648_n.png.jpeg?t=1460182699

This is the inside of my content xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="8"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_emotions"
tools:context="com.example.chadymaebarinan.emoji_express.Needs"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundnew">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/kid"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ME"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="11"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonAngry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/angrybutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonHappy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/happybutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSad"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/sadbutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Angry"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Happy"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sad"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:id="@+id/buttonPainful"
                android:src="@drawable/painfulbutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonScared"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/scaredbutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonInLove"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/inlovebutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Painful"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Scared"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="In Love"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonTired"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/tiredbutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonEmbarrased"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/embarrasedbutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonConfused"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/confusedbutton"
                android:background="@null"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tired"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Embarrased"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Confused"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you guys for helping. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this method help you:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="me"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="me"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, the image button showed up bigger but unfortunately the last 3 image buttons aren't aligned properly on the screen. It split on half on a small screen. :)

Comment: add a pic what you want and what happening now